# Possible bug in Mathematica?

Tags: manipulate

I am having trouble with the simple code:

```
Manipulate[k, {k, 0, 10}]
```

Which gives as an output the usual manipulate box, however, most of the times when scrolling the values for $k$, the manipulate freezes and gives as output

> The kernel is not responding to a Dynamic Evaluation. You may either choose to abort or restart...

Instead, if I restart my PC and open Mathematica and enter the above code, it works. Subsequently, if I work on another nb, and then I open a fresh new one (by restarting the software), I get the same error as above.

I am currently using *Mathematica 11.2* on Windows 10 (Fresh new install).

**Is anyone else experiencing this issue?**

*ALSO:*

I tried with one of the examples on the documentation center for Manipulate

```
Manipulate[x, {{x, 1}, 0, 5}, {x, Range[5]}]
```

and I get the same error with the following messagge:

[image: Manipulate error]

Comment: I get the same issue on Windows 10 using `Mathematica 11.2`.

Comment: No problem here. Works fine. Windows 7 64 bit. Mathematica 11.2.  You way `on Windows`  but which windows?

Comment: @Nasser Latest Windows 10

Comment: No problem on MMA 11.0, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Works fine with MMA 11.0.1 on macos 10.13.3.